# UIView does not react to touches of gesture recognizers

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a problem which I can't get solved. I searched yesterday the whole day for a solution.But didn't get it fixed. I'm making an calendar app with a dayView. This dayview consists of multiple views.

I have the following views

```
- DayView
    - topBackgroundView
         - alldaygridView
            - MAEventView (events on that Day that are all day)
    - Scrollview
        - Gridview
           - MAEventView (normal events)
```

The framework that I used puts the `Alldaygridview` also in the `scrollview`. But I wanted that allday events always are visible, so I put them inside the `topbackgroundView`.

Now the problem is that the `MAEventview` does not react to touches when I put the `AlldayGridview` inside the `topBackgroundView`. Also a simple `tapgesture` is not working.

If already tried to set `UserinteractionEnabled` to YES on every view !

Like I said I'm searching for a long time now and didn't find a solution. So I hope anybody here can help me!

If you want to look at the source code:

[dayView.h](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/71b84b8ae042528c78b9)
[dayView.m](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8a3e535bea1c56fc6218)

Any help is really appreciated !

Comment: Are you using `UIGestureRecognizer`? If so, you need to set the `cancelsTouchesInView` property to `NO`.

Comment: @GuyKogus I have a longpressGesture on my GridView. But I have no gesturerecognizers on my Alldaygridview

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it would be the problem of hierarchy. Make sure that each of your `MAEventView` is on top, precisely on top of your `topBackGroundView`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to overwrite hittest as they might be stoped and see if this method is getting called at all

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: This does not return anything ?

Comment: did you put it in your AlldayGridview class?

Comment: then try to return YES on the BOOL pointinside method and check again

Comment: Still no luck. It does not print anything into my console. Could you please take a look at my source code. Maybe you understand my problem better then

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52575/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-panayot-panayotov)